# Error Connecting to Existing Database with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am tryoing to connect to a mysql database with PHP.  My code in the pho file is:

```
try {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=BurgerBar", 
            "root", "root");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $response = "Failed to connect: ";
        $response .= $e->getMessage();
        die($response);
    }
```

When I run the code in my browser I get

```
Failed to connect: SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'burgerbar'
```

However when I enter mysql in my terminal logging in as root using password root and run

```
show databases;
```

I get

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| BurgerBar          |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
```

So it shows it exists in mysql.  I am using MAMP and cannot figure this out.

Comment: ^Kids a god sent.  Thanks @Twister1002

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the correct database? Could there possibly be two servers of MySQL?

Comment: Oooh did 127.0.0.1 work?

Comment: Also, to point out, UNIX-like systems use case-sensitive names. So burgerbar is different of BurgerBar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your connection string from localhost to the ip that MAMP uses instead of localhost and add the port that MAMP talks to mysql on. Try this:

`$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=5432;dbname=BurgerBar"`